# Load dynamic functions in iOS app

Tags: ios

I need to create this app with dynamic functions and screens.
    Lets say I got 2 types of users for the app - typeA and typeB.
    If typeA user logs in, he will only be presented and allowed to use functionA  and screenA
    If typeB user logs in, he will be presented with functionA  and screenA  PLUS functionB  and screenB.

When it goes to prod and the app gets installed on the device, it is rarely to happen that 2 types of users will login. It is just typeA or typeB.

Requirement is if its a typeA user that logs in, my app size and memory footprint should only be for functionA  and screenA. So by theory the app should be lighter than that of typeB.

Im not sure on the term here. But its like the original app will only have functionA  and screenA. But it typeB logs in, it will load the other functions and screens dynamically - that is not in the original app.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you want isn't really possible. The binaries are precompiled before they're uploaded so the app size couldn't vary depending on the kind of user unless you cut two different binaries.

Swizzling methods based on user type is possible, though. Let's say you have a User (`user`) with an `isPremium` property. You could do something like this:

```
@IBAction func userTappedButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
   user.IsPremium ? performMethodOne() : performMethodTwo()
}
```

That way if the user is premium method one is called, and if they're not method two is called. Presumably you would need a bunch of these checks all over your app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand but ur example requires both functions to be added and compiled first. What I want is to load the other function dynamically.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that might get near what you want is through using [Active Compilation Conditions](https://miqu.me/blog/2016/07/31/xcode-8-new-build-settings-and-analyzer-improvements/). You would still have to decide which condition to use before cutting the binary though so I don't know if this is what you want.